# Bootstrap not working properly when added in ASP.NET MVC web app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, navbar

I just started using ASP.NET MVC and I wanted to use Bootstrap with it but the navbar is not functioning properly it displays a drop down button even though its on full screen and the button doesn't work properly it displays home, about etc. but only for like 1 second when clicked then it gets minimized immediately here is what it looks like

[image: 1]

I don't have my own html file yet I just wanted to load the default page with the bootstrap

I changed the downloaded bootstrap file to bootstrap-lumen2 and here is how I added it on my web app,

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

    // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
    // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-lumen2.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
}
```

Comment: Press F12 and see if you have any errors in the javascript console

Comment: FWIW: per bootstrap docs the css should be loaded in `<head>` and the js loaded right before the `</body>`  tag